# Create tables using a predefined schema in REST API call in Springboot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

There is a scenario where I need to add entry for every user in a table. There will be around 5-10 records per user and the approximate number of users are approximately 1000. So, if I add the data of every user each day in a single table, the table becomes very heavy and the Read/Write operations in the table would take some time to return the data(which would be mostly for a particular user)

The tech stack for back-end is **Spring-boot** and **PostgreSQL**.

Is there any way to create a new table for every user dynamically from the java code and is it really a good way to manage the data, or should all the data should be in a single table.

I'm concerned about the performance of the queries once there are many records in case of a single table holding data for every user.

The model will contain the similar things like userName, userData, time, etc.

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating one table per user is not a good practice. Based on the information you provided, 10000 rows are created per day. Any RDBMS will be able to perfectly handle this amount of data without any performance issues.

By making use of indexing and partitioning, you will be able to address any potential performance issues.

PS: It is always recommended to define a retention period for data you want to keep in operational database. I am not sure about your use-case, but if possible define a retention period and move older data out of operational table into a backup storage.